# Using native modules with React native and swift

Tags: swift, react-native, react-native-native-module

I'm just getting started with React native and made some code with Swift and my question is, do I need to unlink the project and rebuild everytime i change a piece of code within my swift file ? Because now I made some changes inside the swift file but it's not applying to my react-native front end.